# How can I call setState not in class widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

How can I add a card to list, without rewriting architecture. I have split the entity home page and map. I need, with a long press on one of the cards, add its copy to the home page.

```
import 'package:myapp/models/event.dart';

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static List<Event> events = [
    Event(name: "Name 1", location: "loc 1", startDateTime: DateTime.now()),
    Event(name: "Name 2", location: "loc 2", startDateTime: DateTime.now()),
   ...
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: events.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return EventCard(
            event: events[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is necessary to add a card with a long press. See function onLongPress

```
import 'package:myapp/models/event.dart';
 
class _EventCardState extends State<EventCard> {
  bool isEnable = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.red[300],
      shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7, horizontal: 20),
      child: ListTile(
        enabled: isEnable,
        title: Text(
          widget.event.name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          "${widget.event.location} ${widget.event.startDateTime}",
        ),
        leading: Icon(Icons.search),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            this.isEnable = !isEnable;
          }),
        ),
        onLongPress: () {
          // How add copy card
          print("Long tap on search");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or similar plugin for state management. You can read more about state management in [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).
2. Define a global variable (thanks to [randal-schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)). Create a file that named like `card.dart` and put a variable to it:

```dart
final itemsInCard = <Item>[];
```

And from tap you just need to add a new item to card:

```dart
onTap() {
  itemsInCard.add(newItem);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a class just to hold a singleton.  This isn't Java.  You can just put the variable at the global level.  If you insist on a class, I'd make Card.items a getter to populate _instance if needed first.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks, I'm updated the answer.

Comment: And, I'd actually suggest something like RiverPod or Provider now that I think about it... you're definitely gonna wanna rebuild stuff when the list changes.

Comment: I made a global variable with a list of cards, and when clicking on a card, a copy of this card is added to the list, but it is not displayed on the screen.  To display it, call the setState () function of HomeState.  How can I do this from the Card class?

Comment: You can put `setState()` to callback after `push` and back after second screen. But for your case, recommend to use Provider or a similar state management plugin. It may be complex at early app development state but helpful when app evolve.